# Как получить id юзера aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Нужно получить id пользователя, который использует бота. Как можно это сделать в aiogram?

Comment: message.from_user.id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Получение ID юзера осуществляется с помощью message.from_user.id. Для того чтобы получить любую информацию о сообщении нужно "обращаться" в message, там вы много информации о самом сообщении - от кого, во сколько и т.д.. Я реализовал небольшой пример который выводит ID пользователя в ответном сообщении, или же после нажатии на Inline кнопку

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token = "BOT TOKEN HERE")

dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    keyboard_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    user_id_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Получить ID пользывателя из Inline кнопки', callback_data= 'user_id')
    keyboard_markup.row(user_id_btn)
    await message.answer(f"Ваш ID: {message.from_user.id}", reply_markup=keyboard_markup)
 
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='user_id')
async def user_id_inline_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.answer(f"Ваш ID: {callback_query.from_user.id}", True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удачи!