# Aiogram. Как сделать так чтобы бот отправлял user id пользователю при использовании команды /start

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Бот должен отправлять пользователю его же user id при использовании команды /start 
Прямо как в боте @getmyid_bot

Comment: Ну раз нужно, значит возьмите и отправьте.

Comment: ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1249474/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-id-%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-aiogram устарел.

Comment: @10001001 Я смог добиться желаемого результата только с групповыми чатами. С личными сообщениями пока затруднительно.